# how to detect accurate HTML container height when container childs are dynamically rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to summarize my problem in points. Hope this helps.

- I have a ContextMenu component in React
- I am trying to detect its height and position it properly in the screen.
- It gets rendered when user right clicks on the document
- elements inside ContextMenu component are dynamically rendered. Suppose on a perticular condition out of 10, 6 elements are rendered. and they make take some time to render.
- so height of inside elements can not be calculated untill they are rendered fully.
- so height of ContextMenu component also can not be calculated untill child elements are rendered fully.

Now my question is that how can I detect accurate height of ContextMenu component??

Comment: did you try setTimeout?

Comment: why do you need to detect the height? depending on your need, there can be different solutions. If you don't really need to calculate etc. you can set a height. or max height to all it's children. so you will already know their heights.

Comment: If I use maxHeight @DenizKaradağ, then the child elements may render with a less height also. I know that max but not the current. I was detecting height of the component so that I can determine whether it's rendering outside viewport or not. Then position it properly.

Comment: @SabrinaLuo suppose I use a setTimeout, then I have to show loader after user right clicks. It will not be efficient. will it? Except that setTimeout is uncertain. do we have any pattern to get a callback when all childs are rendered and committed to DOM?

Comment: @AyanBanerjee I don't know the context of the app but what you try is really not so beneficial unless you must have it. setting up the values like overflow hidden, box-sizing borderbox etc. so you limit the content's behaviour and make it predictable. Otherwise, until your components are in DOM, you can't measure them. So only option is to manipulate dom after render, which may be visible to user or show loading sign etc. then render. but I am not sure if it is user friendly